# Sbt Error retrieving required libraries

Tags: windows, scala, sbt

I tried updating sbt to 0.13.15, and now whenever i try to run sbt i get the following error. I'm not behind any proxy and the .pom link mentioned in the error downloads without a problem in the browser. Before upgrade sbt 0.13.7 worked without any problem for me. I'm on windows 10.

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.15  (this may take some time)...

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
    problem while downloading module descriptor: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/ivy/ivy/2.3.0-sbt-48dd0744422128446aee9ac31aa356ee203cc9f4/ivy-2.3.0-sbt-48dd0744422128446aee9ac31aa356ee203cc9f4.pom: Read timed out (19292ms)

            module not found: org.scala-sbt.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-sbt-48dd0744422128446aee9ac31aa356ee203cc9f4

    ==== local: tried

      C:\Users\Kamil\.ivy2\local\org.scala-sbt.ivy\ivy\2.3.0-sbt-48dd0744422128446aee9ac31aa356ee203cc9f4\ivys\ivy.xml

      -- artifact org.scala-sbt.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-sbt-48dd0744422128446aee9ac31aa356ee203cc9f4!ivy.jar:

      C:\Users\Kamil\.ivy2\local\org.scala-sbt.ivy\ivy\2.3.0-sbt-48dd0744422128446aee9ac31aa356ee203cc9f4\jars\ivy.jar

    ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried

      file:/C:/Users/Kamil/.sbt/preloaded/org.scala-sbt.ivy/ivy/2.3.0-sbt-48dd0744422128446aee9ac31aa356ee203cc9f4/ivys/ivy.xml

    ==== local-preloaded: tried

      file:/C:/Users/Kamil/.sbt/preloaded/org/scala-sbt/ivy/ivy/2.3.0-sbt-48dd0744422128446aee9ac31aa356ee203cc9f4/ivy-2.3.0-sbt-48dd0744422128446aee9ac31aa356ee203cc9f4.pom

      -- artifact org.scala-sbt.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-sbt-48dd0744422128446aee9ac31aa356ee203cc9f4!ivy.jar:

      file:/C:/Users/Kamil/.sbt/preloaded/org/scala-sbt/ivy/ivy/2.3.0-sbt-48dd0744422128446aee9ac31aa356ee203cc9f4/ivy-2.3.0-sbt-48dd0744422128446aee9ac31aa356ee203cc9f4.jar

    ==== Maven Central: tried

      https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/ivy/ivy/2.3.0-sbt-48dd0744422128446aee9ac31aa356ee203cc9f4/ivy-2.3.0-sbt-48dd0744422128446aee9ac31aa356ee203cc9f4.pom

    ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

      https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt.ivy/ivy/2.3.0-sbt-48dd0744422128446aee9ac31aa356ee203cc9f4/ivys/ivy.xml

    ==== sbt-ivy-snapshots: tried

      https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.scala-sbt.ivy/ivy/2.3.0-sbt-48dd0744422128446aee9ac31aa356ee203cc9f4/ivys/ivy.xml

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

            :: org.scala-sbt.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-sbt-48dd0744422128446aee9ac31aa356ee203cc9f4: not found

            ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::



:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
unresolved dependency: org.scala-sbt.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-sbt-48dd0744422128446aee9ac31aa356ee203cc9f4: not found
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
Error: Could not retrieve sbt 0.13.15
```

Comment: Did your network connection go down? This type of error can occur if SBT is unable to resolve the remote repositories. Have you re-tried the command?

Comment: Yes, i tried it many times and each time i get exactly the same error.

Comment: Do you have a `project\build.properties` file that you're using to specify _sbt_ 0.13.15? If so, can you post it's contents? If not, which version of _sbt_ do you have installed? Do you have a `C:\Users\Kamil\.sbt\repositories` file? If so, can you post that too?

Comment: I have just downloaded the latest sbt (mostly to get the `sbt new` feature) and am trying to launch it outside any scala project (so there's no project/build.properties file). The repositories file is not present (i guess i got rid of it when nuking my previous sbt installation).

Comment: Sbt seems to work fine in my project with sbt 0.13.7 specified in the build.properties file, after changing it to `sbt.version = 0.13.15` the same error occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only need to create a `.sbt\repositories` file if you're doing something special (such as using a local artifact server, such as *Nexus* or *Artifactory*). Maybe your installation went a little awry? Try creating this file (`C:\Users\Kamil\.sbt\repositories`) with the following contents, then retry your build.

```
[repositories]
  local
  sbt-releases-repo: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  sbt-plugins-repo: http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  maven-central: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
```

Comment: This worked. I think what did the trick is maven-central being specified here to use http and not https. Seems like sbt has a problem with resolving dependencies over https?

Comment: That's an interesting point. This might indicate a problem with the sites' certificates, if that's the case, which should be validated by the contents of the `%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\cacerts` file (`/etc/ssl/certs/java/cacerts` on _Linux_). Are you using an old version of _Java_?

Comment: No, i also updated to latest jdk during the upgrade.

Comment: Would you have a firewall that's blocking HTTPS access to the repositories? That's about the only other possibility I can think of. I'm using HTTPS with _sbt_ without any problems, so the certificates are OK and so is the current `cacerts` file.

Comment: Tried it with the windows firewall turned off and it still showed that error. It's my home computer, so there shouldn't be any corporate firewalls in the way either.