# Run sbt and get `unresolved dependency: Received fatal alert: access_denied`

Tags: java, playframework, sbt

I'm new one for playframwork. My intellij cannot import sbt project so that tried to run `sbt` directly.

Run: `sbt` at empty folder and get this:

```
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 1.2.8  (this may take some time)...

:: problems summary ::
:::: WARNINGS
                module not found: org.scala-sbt#sbt;1.2.8

        ==== local: tried

          C:\Users\leih.CORPDOM\.ivy2\local\org.scala-sbt\sbt\1.2.8\ivys\ivy.xml

          -- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;1.2.8!sbt.jar:

          C:\Users\leih.CORPDOM\.ivy2\local\org.scala-sbt\sbt\1.2.8\jars\sbt.jar

        ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried

          file:/C:/Users/leih.CORPDOM/.sbt/preloaded/org.scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.8/ivys/ivy.xml

        ==== local-preloaded: tried

          file:/C:/Users/leih.CORPDOM/.sbt/preloaded/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.8/sbt-1.2.8.pom

          -- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;1.2.8!sbt.jar:

          file:/C:/Users/leih.CORPDOM/.sbt/preloaded/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.8/sbt-1.2.8.jar

        ==== Maven Central: tried

          https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.8/sbt-1.2.8.pom

          -- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;1.2.8!sbt.jar:

          https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.8/sbt-1.2.8.jar

        ==== sbt-maven-releases: tried

          https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-releases/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.8/sbt-1.2.8.pom

          -- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;1.2.8!sbt.jar:

          https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-releases/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.8/sbt-1.2.8.jar

        ==== sbt-maven-snapshots: tried

          https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-snapshots/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.8/sbt-1.2.8.pom

          -- artifact org.scala-sbt#sbt;1.2.8!sbt.jar:

          https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-snapshots/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.8/sbt-1.2.8.jar

        ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried

          https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.8/ivys/ivy.xml

        ==== sbt-ivy-snapshots: tried

          https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.8/ivys/ivy.xml

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

                :: org.scala-sbt#sbt;1.2.8: not found

                ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::


:::: ERRORS
        Server access Error: Received fatal alert: access_denied url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.8/sbt-1.2.8.pom

        Server access Error: Received fatal alert: access_denied url=https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.8/sbt-1.2.8.jar

        Server access Error: Received fatal alert: access_denied url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-releases/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.8/sbt-1.2.8.pom

        Server access Error: Received fatal alert: access_denied url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-releases/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.8/sbt-1.2.8.jar

        Server access Error: Received fatal alert: access_denied url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-snapshots/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.8/sbt-1.2.8.pom

        Server access Error: Received fatal alert: access_denied url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/maven-snapshots/org/scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.8/sbt-1.2.8.jar

        Server access Error: Received fatal alert: access_denied url=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.8/ivys/ivy.xml

        Server access Error: Received fatal alert: access_denied url=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/ivy-snapshots/org.scala-sbt/sbt/1.2.8/ivys/ivy.xml


:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
unresolved dependency: org.scala-sbt#sbt;1.2.8: not found
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
  (see C:\Users\leih.CORPDOM\.sbt\boot\update.log for complete log)
Error: Could not retrieve sbt 1.2.8
```

My java version on win10:

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_181"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Zulu 8.31.0.1-win64) (build 1.8.0_181-b02)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Zulu 8.31.0.1-win64) (build 25.181-b02, mixed mode)
```

Refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43984715/sbt-error-retrieving-required-libraries) to add `repositories` at `.stb` and re-run `sbt`, get maven repo success. But failed when I tried to `sbt run` run at `hello-world` smaple project:

repositories is:

```
[repositories]
  local
  sbt-releases-repo: http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  sbt-plugins-repo: http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/, [organization]/[module]/(scala_[scalaVersion]/)(sbt_[sbtVersion]/)[revision]/[type]s/[artifact](-[classifier]).[ext]
  maven-central: http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
```

Added proxy by:

`set JAVA_OPTS=-Dhttp.proxyHost=yourserver -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080`
re run `sbt` failed.

Then added `.sbtopts`: `-Dsbt.repository.secure=false`, but still failed.

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
...
[warn]  typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for com.typesafe#npm_2.12;1.2.1: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe/npm_2.12/1.2.1/jars/npm_2.12.jar: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: access_denied
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]          org.scala-lang.modules:scala-parser-combinators_2.12:1.1.1
[warn]            +- com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-native-packager:1.3.20 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]            +- com.typesafe.play:sbt-plugin:2.7.3 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (C:\Users\leih.CORPDOM\Documents\node\Exercise\play-samples-play-java-hello-world-tutorial\project\plugins.sbt#L1-2)
[warn]            +- default:play-samples-play-java-hello-world-tutorial-build:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]          org.webjars:webjars-locator-core:0.36
[warn]            +- com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-web:1.4.4 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]            +- com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-js-engine:1.2.3 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]            +- com.typesafe.play:sbt-plugin:2.7.3 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (C:\Users\leih.CORPDOM\Documents\node\Exercise\play-samples-play-java-hello-world-tutorial\project\plugins.sbt#L1-2)
[warn]            +- default:play-samples-play-java-hello-world-tutorial-build:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]          com.typesafe.play:twirl-compiler_2.12:1.4.2
[warn]            +- com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-twirl:1.4.2 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]            +- com.typesafe.play:sbt-plugin:2.7.3 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (C:\Users\leih.CORPDOM\Documents\node\Exercise\play-samples-play-java-hello-world-tutorial\project\plugins.sbt#L1-2)
[warn]            +- default:play-samples-play-java-hello-world-tutorial-build:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]          com.lightbend.play:play-file-watch_2.12:1.1.8
...
[error]         typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for com.typesafe#npm_2.12;1.2.1: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe/npm_2.12/1.2.1/jars/npm_2.12.jar: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: access_denied
[error]
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.resolveAndRetrieve(IvyActions.scala:332)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$updateEither$1(IvyActions.scala:208)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.$anonfun$withModule$1(Ivy.scala:239)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.$anonfun$withIvy$1(Ivy.scala:204)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.sbt$internal$librarymanagement$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:70)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:95)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:80)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:99)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:60)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:50)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
[error]         at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:199)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:196)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:238)
[error]         at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:193)
[error]         at sbt.librarymanagement.ivy.IvyDependencyResolution.update(IvyDependencyResolution.scala:20)
[error]         at sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.update(DependencyResolution.scala:56)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.scala:45)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12(LibraryManagement.scala:93)
[error]         at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:68)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$19(LibraryManagement.scala:106)
[error]         at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:224)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(LibraryManagement.scala:106)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted(LibraryManagement.scala:89)
[error]         at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChanged$1(Tracked.scala:149)
[error]         at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:120)
[error]         at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask$5(Defaults.scala:2561)
[error]         at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
[error]         at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:67)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:269)
[error]         at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:278)
[error]         at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:269)
[error]         at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:178)
[error]         at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:37)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#sbt-routes-compiler_2.12;2.7.3: Resolution failed several times for dependency: com.typesafe.play#sbt-routes-compiler_2.12;2.7.3 {compile=[default(compile)]}::
```

Now I'm very confused.

Appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I opened the sample project as the interllij project and `install scala plugin` twice(first failed) and restart intellij. Build the project with `JAVA_OPTS`, and failed with dependency evcited error.

So I delete `.sbt` and `.lvy2` the two folders and reinstall `sbt` and restart computer.

Rerun project success.

Here is my vm options:

```sh
-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyServer
-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
-Dsbt.repository.secure=false
```

and haven't repository file.

---

<del>Still don't know why failed at the bash/cmd</del>

---

update:

It's wrong if don't set https_proxy.
Create `HTTPS_PROXY` and `HTTP_PROXY` with windows way. If the proxy server doesn't accept https, add http protocol like `HTTPS_PROXY=http://proxyServer:port`